# Session is cleared when executing a new API call after passport facebook login

Tags: express, react-native, passport.js, express-session, passport-facebook

I'm creating a React Native app in which the user should be able to login with Facebook (of course). I'm working with express-session (in combination with MongoDB to store the sessions) integrated with passport (local strategy) and passport-facebook (Facebook strategy) in the node backend to implement some sort of session management where the user doesn't need to login again after he closes the app.
Everything is working fine for the local strategy; user can login, and make requests to the API until the session expires. 
I'm trying to get the Facebook strategy up and running, but I'm faced with an issue I've been trying to fix for days now...

Using React Native, the app will pop up a window asking for your Facebook credentials, asks if the app can use the necessary information of your profile. This happens in the following code:

```
// Set up Linking
componentDidMount() {
    // Add event listener to handle OAuthLogin:// URLs
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
    // Launched from an external URL
    Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
        if (url) {
            this.handleOpenURL({ url });
        }
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove event listener
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}

loginWithFacebook() {
    this.openURL('http://localhost:3002/v1/auth/facebook');
}

// Open URL in a browser
openURL(url) {
    // Use SafariView on iOS
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        SafariView.show({
            url: url,
            fromBottom: true
        });
    }
    // Or Linking.openURL on Android
    else {
        Linking.openURL(url);
    }
}

handleOpenURL({ url }) {
    const [, user_string] = url.match(/user=([^#]+)/);
    console.log(JSON.parse(decodeURI(user_string)));

    let result = JSON.parse(decodeURI(user_string));

    if(result.success) {
        this.props.loginFbComplete(result.user);
    } else {

    }

    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        SafariView.dismiss();
    }
}
```

loginWithFacebook() is called when clicking on a button in the Login screen. Everything runs accordingly to plan, so Facebook developers account is correctly configured.
In the backend, my passport-facebook strategy is configured like this:

```
// Register Facebook Passport strategy
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy.Strategy(facebook,
    function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            Users.findOne(
                {
                    Provider: 'facebook',
                    ProviderId: profile.id,
                    Email: profile.emails[0].value
                }, (err, user) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return done(err, null);
                    } else {
                        if (!user) {
                            let providerData = profile._json;
                            providerData.accessToken = accessToken;
                            providerData.refreshToken = refreshToken;

                            let providerUserProfile = {
                                FullName: profile.displayName,
                                FirstName: profile.name.givenName,
                                LastName: profile.name.familyName,
                                Email: profile.emails[0].value,
                                Provider: 'facebook',
                                ProviderId: profile.id,
                                ProviderData: providerData,
                            };

                            let newUser = new Users(providerUserProfile);
                            newUser.save((err) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    return done(err, null);
                                } else {
                                    return done(null, newUser);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            return done(null, user);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    }
));
```

deserializeUser function:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   Users.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
   });
});
```

serializeUser function:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});
```

For the authentication route, following is added:

```
router.route('/auth/facebook')
.get((req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('facebook')(req, res, next)
});
```

For the callback route after successful/failed Facebook login, following is added:

```
router.route('/auth/facebook/callback')
.get(loginFbUser);
const loginFbUser = (req, res) => {
passport.authenticate('facebook', (error, user, info) => {
    let result = {};

    console.log('REQ SESSION 1', req.session);

    if (error || !user) {
        result = {success: false, message: info.message};
        return res.redirect('OAuthLogin://login?user=' + JSON.stringify(result))
    } else if (user) {
        req.login(user, loginErr => {
            if (loginErr) {
                result = {success: false, message: loginErr.message};
            } else {
                Users.findOneAndUpdate({_id: user._id}, {LastOnline: new Date()}, {new: true}).lean().exec((err, testUser) => {
                    if (err) {
                        result = {success: false, message: err.message};
                    } else if (!testUser) {
                        result = {success: false, message: 'User not found.'};
                    } else {
                        result = {success: true, user: testUser};
                    }

                    console.log('isAuthenticated?', req.isAuthenticated());
                    req.session.save(function() {
                        console.log('session after save', req.session);
                        res.redirect('OAuthLogin://login?user=' + JSON.stringify(result));
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
})(req, res);
};
```

The first console.log with show a session with no passport (user._id) set in the session.
After the req.login() function, I can see clearly that the user is authenticated through the req.isAuthenticated() method. I'm forcing to save the session to the MongoDB with req.session.save(). In the last console.log, I can see a difference with the first console.log-statement; user (_id) is added to the session. 
I redirect back to the correct route in my React Native app to catch the result of the facebook login. Here comes the issue: when I execute another request after the login, the user session is gone, it's empty, the user is unauthorised in fact to execute any further requests to the API, the session is cleared, and I have no idea why.

Does anyone have an idea what this could be?